# Excel VBA If statement multiple conditions runtime error 13

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, type-mismatch

Hello whenever I try to run the following code I get a runtime error 13 type mismatch and I dont know why or how to fix this.

The idea is that if a = 8 and the first digit in cell(i,c) = 6 or 4 then excel should so something.

````
Dim a as integer
Dim c as integer

If a = 8 And (CInt(Left(.Cells(i, c), 1)) = 6 Or CInt(Left(.Cells(i, c), 1)) = 4) Then```
````

Comment: What is in the cells you are processing? Does it fail on every cell, or just some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the cell you are reading is either empty or don't start with a digit, `CInt` will throw that runtime error 13.

You could use the `Val`-function instead (will return 0 for non-numeric strings), or you could check for the character `"6"` resp. `"4"` instead. I also would suggest to use an intermediate variable to save the character you are checking, makes the code much more readable.

```
dim firstChr as string
firstChr = Left(.Cells(i, c))
If a = 8 And (val(firstChr) = 6 Or val(firstChr) = 4) Then
' or
If a = 8 And (firstChr = "6" Or firstChr = "4") Then
```

Comment: That makes it less readable, as "c" is also used as the column index!

Comment: @DS_London: You are right, good catch. Have done my tests without the definitions of `a` and `d` of OPs code (and use `c` as name for a single character all the time). Will update the answer.

Comment: @FunThomas: **If the content of the cell you are reading is either empty or don't start with a digit, CInt will throw that runtime error 13.**

Good to know, that was exactly the issue here, thank you very much! The if statement also changes to value of i which led to a cell that had some text in it which probably caused that error, for the other cells it works as intended.